# Can we show some dynamic text along with the marker on Google maps in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add some text under marker like in the picture mentioned below,I'm using google maps, Swift

[image]

I want to add some text under my marker. There is a way to do that?

My Code

```
self.mapView.clear();
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds();
        if let lat = alert?.latitude, let lon = alert?.longitude{
            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: position);
            marker.title = alert?.deviceName;
            marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
            marker.map = mapView;
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(position);
        }
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds)
        self.mapView.animate(with: update);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maps SDK for iOS Utility Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) to customize the marker. See [CustomerMarkerViewController](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/app/CustomMarkerViewController.m) as an example.